# Distributed Locking service

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I have a problem where several processes on different machines are each entering a critical section at the same time. I want to create a generic solution where a machine can request a lease for a critical section from a web service and renew it as long as it needs it (I.e. every 5 minutes). My understanding is Zookeeper and Paxos implementations are popular for solving distributed coordination problems. My problem; however, seems simpler than most use cases so I was wondering if it would be overkill and an easier solution is possible. I am wondering if anyone knows any solutions out there; I am new to distributed systems.

The service would need to have relatively fast response times. Data resiliency would be good to have. Ideally, one can send an http request to the server for the lock so it would be language agnostic.

Comment: Take a look at redis.

Comment: You could also look into Shedlock (https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring)